# AutoScroll Css + Run Function Multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I keep my scroll div go to the bottom when loads new HTML? Also, I would like to know how to run the ajax function every 3 seconds.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("button[id^='select-']").click( function worker() {
        var containerName = $(this).attr('name');
        console.log(containerName);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'DockerLogs',
            data: {containerName: containerName},
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                $('#logs').empty();
                document.getElementById('logs').innerHTML = result;
            },
            error: function () {

            },
            complete: function () {
                setTimeout(worker, 2000);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="logs" class="logs" style="margin-top: 25px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

setInterval(function(){

//your ajax function name

}, 3000);

//your ajax function